# VBA Recordset Filter Wildcard 'Ending With' Not working- Error 3001

Tags: excel, vba, ado, recordset

I am reading an Excel file into an ADO Recordset using `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`. As per snb's excellent [article](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_ADODB_recordset_en.html#L_11) on ADO I have been using a number of filters that work perfectly, all except for the "Ends With" filter, for which I am receiving `Error 3001: "Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another"`. The "Ends With" filter is essentially a wildcard filter, just like one would use in SQL, and the syntax is as follows:

`"[FieldName] LIKE '*searchterm'"`.

Saying that I have tried all combinations of wildcard characters (`*, %`) with no luck. The [microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/filter-property?view=sql-server-2017) on the Recordset Filter property says the following about the use of the LIKE operator:

"In a LIKE clause, you can use a wildcard at the beginning and end of the pattern. For example, you can use LastName Like '*mit*'. Or with LIKE you can use a wildcard only at the end of the pattern. For example, LastName Like 'Smit*'.

The above seems unclear, but I believe that they are saying the following:

Beginning And End: LastName Like '*mit*' is legal 
Begins With: LastName Like 'Smit*' is legal

BUT

End With: LastName Like '*t' Is Illegall???

If that's the case, then I know that an Ends with filter is not possible as one may intuitively think, and I hope someone could provide an alternative solution that will mimic an "Ends With" wildcard filter.

If not, then I hope that someone can point me to what I am missing. All suggestions, ideas, or answers are greatly appreciated.

Below is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SheetToRecrdset()

 Dim strSourceFile As String
 Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim RcrdsetSheet As ADODB.Recordset

  strSourceFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
        With Conn
             .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
             .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strSourceFile & _
             ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"
             .Open
        End With

    Set RcrdsetSheet = New ADODB.Recordset

     RcrdsetSheet.Open "SELECT * FROM [Data$] Where Not IsNull([Row_ID])", _
     Conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

        If RcrdsetSheet.EOF = True Or RcrdsetSheet.BOF = True Then
            MsgBox "For some reason the query did not return any data. Try closing" & _
            " and and opening the file again.", vbCritical, "Error: No Results Returned"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'Example String to filter: "MRQ"

        'CONTAINS FILTER WORKS
        RcrdsetSheet.Filter = "[LOCATION] LIKE '*M*'"

        'BEGINS WITH FILTER WORKS
        RcrdsetSheet.Filter = "[LOCATION] LIKE 'M*'"


       'ENDS WITH FILTER DOESN'T WORK
       'RcrdsetSheet.Filter = "[LOCATION] LIKE '*Q'"     'Error 3001

       '@TinMan's Suggestions
       'RcrdsetSheet.Filter = "[LOCATION] LIKE '*Q''"    'Error 2147024809
       'RcrdsetSheet.Filter = "[LOCATION] LIKE '*Q'''"   'Error 3001
       RcrdsetSheet.Filter = "[LOCATION] LIKE ""*Q'"""   'Returns no Records

       Debug.Print RcrdsetSheet.RecordCount 'Returns 0

       Dim arrayOut As Variant

       arryOut = RcrdsetSheet.GetRows       'Error 3021


End Sub
```

Sample Data Example:

[image]

Also, note that the data type of the field is 
adVarWChar, DataTypeEnum = 202, which Indicates a null-terminated Unicode character string.

Comment: Weird. I am able to replicate this issue. Even weirder, this SQL seems to work `SELECT * FROM [Data$] where [Location] like '%Q'` on the recordset open.

Comment: if you like, you can just skip to the end of my post for the answer but I think it is worth reading..lol.

Comment: @RyanWildry I was only half right.  ADO Recordset Filters can not begin with a wildcard without ending with a wildcard.  I  posted a workaround that might interest you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### New Answer

My original answer has some valuable information about using quotes and singles inside queries but does not address the OP's question.

Although not really clear, this excerpt from [ADO » Recordset » Filter](http://www.devguru.com/content/technologies/ado/recordset-filter.html)  explains it

> If you use the LIKE operator, you can also use the * or % wildcards as the last character in the string or as the first and last character in the string.

When using LIKE operator with the ADODB Recordset Filter property, if the Filter begins with a wildcard (* or %) then it must end with a wildcard  (* or %).  Wildcards in the middle of a Filter string do not work.

So just because we can not use a wildcard with the LIKE operator using an ADO Recordset Filter without ending the Filter with a wildcard doesn't mean that we cannot make it work!

### Let's Hack the System!

- Add a calculated field to the query that returns the last character
- Use % for the last character of the ADO Recordset Filter
- Filter the original field using Like *somevalue% and calculated field = last character

### Test Code

```
Sub Test()
    TestFilter "(Location Like '*Q%') AND (LOCATIONLastChar = '''')"
End Sub

Sub TestFilter(Filter As String)
    Const BaseConnectionString = "Data Source=@FullName;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'"
    Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection, rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim SQL As String

    Set Conn = New ADODB.Connection
    With Conn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = Replace(BaseConnectionString, "@FullName", ThisWorkbook.FullName)
        .Open
    End With

    SQL = "SELECT *, Right(LOCATION,1) AS LOCATIONLastChar FROM [Data$] Where Not IsNull(Row_ID)"

    rs.Open SQL, Conn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

    rs.Filter = Filter


    If Not rs.BOF Then
        Worksheets.Add
        Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    End If
    rs.Close
    Conn.Close
End Sub
```

### Original Post

When I have a problem writing a query I use the Access Query Designer to help me write it.

```
SELECT Table1.Field1
FROM Table1
WHERE (((Table1.Field1) Like "a'*"));
```

Notice that the designer uses quotes around the filter string.  SQL can use either double or single quotes for strings.

If you use double quotes for string values, any quotes within the double quotes need to be doubled.

Here is an example:

```
rs.Open "SELECT Table1.Field1 FROM Table1 WHERE (((Table1.Field1) Like ""a'*""));"
```

This is, however, be a pain in the neck to get right.  So what I do is write a couple of helper functions that will double the quotes or single quotes for me.

```
Function getClipBoardText()
    With CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
        .getFromClipBoard
        getClipBoardText = .getText
    End With
End Function

Sub PrintText()
    Dim s As String
    s = getClipBoardText
    Debug.Print Replace(s, Chr(34), String(2, 34))
End Sub
```

Now all I have to do is copy the designer's SQL and run PrintText

[image]

To make a very long story short, simply double the single quote that is wrapped inside single quotes!

```
RcrdsetSheet.Filter = "[LOCATION] LIKE '*Q'''"
```

Here is how you would use the single quotes inside of double quotes

```
RcrdsetSheet.Filter = "[LOCATION] LIKE ""*Q'"""
```

Comment: @TinMan Really appreciate the help! Unfortunately though, it still isn't working for me. Check out the latest edit to my question.

Comment: @TinMan Sounds great! I made another edit to my answer to include more info that I hope will be helpful.

Comment: So you mean that "Ends With" just doesn't work at all no matter how you slice it?

Comment: Well that stinks. Any Ideas for a workaround? Either way, please know that I really appreciate your effort . I've been working on this for two days with no luck so I'll take anything I can get lol.

Comment: The calculated field is an excellent idea, and it works wonderfully. I marked your answer as the answer, because as my question was phrased you definitely answered it. However, in reality, I am running multiple filters at once for an application that I designed in which the user enters a set of criteria filters, each with multiple criteria, and for each filter my procure loops through the filtered records, saves the row indexes to a dictionary and then filters an array that contains the exact same data as the record set based on the row indexes in the dictionary ...continue next....

Comment: I would create a class to hold the main query data in an array.  The class would then be responsible for returning the filtered data.  Recordsets are convenient but they carry overhead.   Working with the data in an Array would be much faster.

Comment: If a filtered record is found, then data is output to another field. 
Something like `Filter1: [BIN] Like '*PROD*' OR [BIN] Like '*HOLD*' ; OutPut: PROD`
`Filter2: [PN_SUB_CATEGORY] Like '200*' OR [LOCATION] Like ' *Q'; OutPut: CLASSIC`
`FilterN: [LOCATION]='SB' OR [LOCATION]='SSB'; Output: SUSPECT`
I am basically filtering based on Filter1, outputing searching the array using `Dict.Exists(arry(i,intSavedRowID)` to output data to an array, clearing the filter, then filtering based on Filter2, outputing to the array, and so on up to FilterN. This has to be  totally dynamic hence my use of

Comment: ` the recordset which accepts a string as filter criteria. Otherwise I would have to autogenerate `If` statements to filter the array itself, which can only be done in VBA by building string of using some sort of complex algorithm, creating a module at run-time using he VBA extensibility library, and then passing the string to the module to be run as code, all of which is just not feasible for me. In simple terms I need to mimic `C#'s` `LINQ` which is just not possible in VBA.

Comment: So based on all of that, how would I make your implementation of "Ends With" work on a recordset that I need to remain open? Or would you have any idea of another approach altogether that would work? Im Sorry for blowing up the comments like this. I would have continued all of this in Chat but my work network won't allow it

Comment: How does the recordset needing to remain open matter?  This should yield the correct results: `  [PN_SUB_CATEGORY] Like '200*' OR ([LOCATION] Like ' *Q%' AND [LOCATIONLast] Like '''') `

Comment: It matters because for each filter, I am reading from the recordset, clearing it, outputting to the array, then repeating for the next filter. Bassically, Each filter has multiple criteria and so there are a set of named filters (each with multiple criteria) from which I create a collection and loop through it. For each item (which is a single filter's criteria string), I send that string to another sub which filters the recordset as described above. So To make your "Ends With" implementation work, I would have to close the recordset, and then re-query it if there is a "Ends With" condition.